# Wildfly 9 Stateless session bean webservice not showing up in Web Service Endpoints

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, wildfly-8, ejb-3.2

I'm quite new to the Wildfly server.

Currently I'm trying to expose a simple Stateless Session Bean as web service. I don't want to use the webModule to define servlet mappings for the web services beans. I want to keep that seperated. 
I just want to expose a simple Stateless Session Bean as web service.

I used the wildfly-javaee7-webapp-ear-blank-archetype as starting point.

In the ejbModule i added a Stateless Session Bean with @WebService annotation.
The ejbModule is packaged in an .ear file, which is deployed to the WildFly Server 9. The deployment shows now error message.

I now expected to see some endpoints in the admin console under web service endpoints as the documentation(https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/JAX-WS+User+Guide) says. But I can't see any endpoints.

What I'm doing wrong ?
How can i access the generated WSDL file of the web service ? 
What is the exact context root when ejb is packaged inside ear file?
Any hints are appreciated.

package eu.sample.testws.service;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.jws.WebService;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class TestWSBean
 */
@Stateless
@WebService(serviceName="TestWSService", name="TestWSServiceName", portName="TestWSPortName", targetNamespace="http://sample.eu")
public class TestWSBean {

```
/**
 * Default constructor. 
 */
public TestWSBean() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


public String sayHello(){
    return "Hello";
}
```

}